# How to return prevent entity escapes from returning in Play?

Tags: html, scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I'm using play 2.6 with Scala and have this bit in my view template:

```
@isActive( liText: String ) = @{
        if ( liText.equals(activeTab) ) "class=\"active\""  else ""
    }
```

But it's rendering this:
`class=&quot;active&quot;`

But I want it to render this:

`"class="active""`

I feel like I'm close but can't quite get it to not use `&quot` in the final HTML. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want it to print `"` instead of `&quot;` or just want it to print extra `"` at the beginning and end?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted the actual " in there. I made a typo, see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Html` to make it print raw html instead of escaping the content:

```
@isActive( liText: String ) = @{
    if ( liText.equals(activeTab) ) @Html("class='active'")  else ""
}
```

Source: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplates#Escaping